# PDF Viewer in Android

Tags: android, pdf, plugins, android-intent, adobe

In my android, I have Adobe PDF reader installed. Now what I am trying to do is that when my PDF is downloaded and show PDF is clicked I am trying to open the PDF in Adobe PDF reader.

Following is the Intent but no option on Adobe PDF Reader Comes:

```
public String showPdf(String fileName) {
File file = new File(fileName);
Log.i("PdfViewer", "open file "+ fileName);
// if (file.exists()) {
Log.i("PdfViewer", "file exist");
try {
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//intent.setData(Uri.parse(fileName));
this.ctx.startActivity(intent);
return "";
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
System.out.println("PdfViewer: Error loading url "+fileName+":"+ e.toString());
return e.toString();
}
```

Can you please suggest an intent to use?

Thanks,
Ankit.

Comment: which context are you using to start the activity.? Are you getting something in the catch block.?

Comment: Sahil,when I click show PDF I get a list of softwares to open but not adobe PDF Reader. no I am not getting anything in catch block.

Comment: first make sure, adobe reader is installed. Second check if the downloaded file is really a pdf file. third, have you tried it with any other pdf viewer.?

Comment: Yes, PDF Viewer is installed but the list has no option of adobe PDF Reader